# converting a twitter date string into a datetime field in excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, time, ms-office

I have a number of excel strings in the format "Mon Nov 25 17:20:47 +0000 2019"

I found an earlier post that recommended using =DATE(RIGHT(O2,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(1 & MID(O2,5,3))),MID(O2,9,2)) to create a usable date field.  However, this drops the time which is an important piece of information.

How can I include the time with the date in order for excel to recognize and sort all the information included in the field?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the same logic with the date formula, but use TIME instead of DATE and of course extract the correct time into the formula =TIME(MID(O2,12,2),MID(O2,15,2),MID(O2,18,2))

Edit:
to combine them both in one field, you will need to add them =DATE(RIGHT(O2,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(1 & MID(O2,5,3))),MID(O2,9,2)) + TIME(MID(O2,12,2),MID(O2,15,2),MID(O2,18,2))

The rationale of this is because: 
Date is expressed in whole numbers i.e. 1 = 01/01/1900, 2 = 02/01/1900, 3 = 03/01/1900... 43794 = 25/11/2019, etc.
Time is expressed as a fraction of the day i.e. 0.5 =  12 hrs/12PM, 0.66666 = 16 hrs/4PM, etc.

so lets say you have 1/1/2019 12.00 PM, the date part that gives 1/1/2019 will be 43466 and the time part will be 0.5. Adding them together will give you 43466.5, and when converted to a date time format it will show as 1/1/2019 12:00 PM.

Comment: Bankar, thank you, but doesn't that put the date and time in separate fields?  Is there a way to put them in one field?

Comment: Please check edit in the answer for explanation on that

Comment: Thank you that worked!  The description was great too.  I tried to give you a up point but i need a few more reputation points before I do that.  I will be sure to come back and do it when I reach that level.

Comment: No probs, thanks and good luck! Formulas in the "Text" categories are helpful in terms of extracting and manipulating cell contents. And you might want to accept the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions to create an unambiguous date string, then turn it into a date/time value with a mathematical operation (adding the time value in a string form).

```
=(MID(A1,9,2)&"-"&MID(A1,5,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))+MID(A1,12,8)
```

You'll need to format the result as something appropriate: eg: `dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm`